# Metafor interactions (not showing complete output)

Tags: interaction, metafor

As part of a mini meta analysis where I want to test 2 moderators, I have used the following code:

```
output <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ factor(discipline) : factor(gender), data=interact_emm, method = "FE")
```

Both gender and discipline have two levels. When I run the analysis, the model output only shows 4 lines:

Model Results:

```
intrcpt                                       0.1334  0.0854  1.5614   6  0.1694  -0.0756    
factor(discipline)hass:factor(gender)men      0.0873  0.1542  0.5659   6  0.5920  -0.2901     
factor(discipline)stem:factor(gender)men      0.1837  0.1194  1.5381   6  0.1749  -0.1086   
factor(discipline)hass:factor(gender)women    0.2918  0.1505  1.9387   6  0.1006  -0.0765
```

Hence, I'm missing one of the interactions - Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: There's no missing line. It's the intercept. This is how interactions work in any regression (including meta-regression).

Comment: This means that the intercept represents the interaction women:stem? thank you

Comment: I think this may be helpful: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:multiple_factors_interactions